# Is there a clever way of finding a map from one set of numbers to another?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations

Imagine that I have a set of subsets of numbers:
$$\{\{1,2,5,6\};\{1,2,7,8\};\{5,6,7,8\}\}$$
and another set of subsets of numbers:
$$\{\{1,2,5,7\};\{1,3,5,8\};\{2,3,7,8\}\}$$
such that I know that there is a map from one set to another.
In such a map, the ordering of a subset does not matter.
For example, the subsets $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{2,1,3\}$ are equivalent.
In this case, the map is the following:
$$\begin{matrix}
1 \rightarrow 1 \\
2 \rightarrow 5 \\
3 \rightarrow 4 \\
4 \rightarrow 6 \\
5 \rightarrow 2 \\
6 \rightarrow 7 \\
7 \rightarrow 3 \\
8 \rightarrow 8 \\
\end{matrix}$$
I found the map by testing all possible permutations (in this case $8!$) and keeping the first one that matched.
However, I wonder if there is an efficient way of finding such a map using, for example, graph theory.

Best.

Comment: What does the nested structure of the lists have to do with anything?

Comment: A map from subsets of the first set to those of the second could be $\{1,2,5,6\} \to \{1,2,5,7\}$, $\{1,2,7,8\} \to \{1,3,5,8\}$, $\{5,6,7,8\} \to \{2,3,7,8\}$ or any of the other five bijective maps or twenty-one non-bijective maps.  But you seem to want more than this, mapping the elements of the subsets.

Comment: You seem to be looking for a permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,2,\dots,8\}$ such that $$\big\{\{\sigma(1),\sigma(2),\sigma(5),\sigma(6)\},\;\{\sigma(1),\sigma(3),\sigma(5),\sigma(8)\},\;\{\sigma(5),\sigma(6),\sigma(7),\sigma(8)\}\big\}$$ is equal to $$\big\{\{1,2,5,7\},\;\{1,3,5,8\},\;\{2,3,7,8\}\big\}.$$ Are you also requiring the $4$-element sets to match up, such as $\{\sigma(1),\sigma(2),\sigma(5),\sigma(6)\} = \{1,2,5,7\}$, or is that a quirk of this particular example?

Answer (score 1):

An ad-hoc approach is to look for properties that are preserved by relabeling elements, and use this to narrow your search. In this example, the first structure has three disjoint pairs of elements that always appear together ($\{1,2\}, \{5,6\}, \{7,8\}$), and these pairs are combined in all three possible ways. The second structure has this property only for $\{1,5\}, \{2,7\}, \{3,8\}$, so a valid map must correspond to a permutation of these pairs and of the elements within each pair. This reduces your search space to $3!\cdot2^3$ permutations (and it's fairly clear that they all work, assuming Misha's interpretation of your requirements).